# Image loaded onto CanvasTexture appears pixelated

Tags: three.js

There's been a-lot of questions around this but none of those have fixed my problem. Any image that I upload onto the object becomes pixelated regardless of the `minFilter` or `magFilter` that I use - and I've used all of them:

```
THREE.NearestFilter
THREE.NearestMipMapNearestFilter
THREE.NearestMipMapLinearFilter
THREE.LinearFilter
THREE.LinearMipMapNearestFilter
THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter
```

Here's the object with a pixelated image:[image: pixelated]

And here's a snapshot of how I'm loading the image on:

```
        // Build a canvas object and add the image to it
        var imageCanvas = this.getCanvas(imageLayer.guid, 'image');
        var imageLoader = new THREE.ImageLoader();

        imageLoader.load(imageUrl, img => { 
            // this.drawImage(img, gr, imageCanvas.canvas, imageCanvas.ctx); 
            var canvas = imageCanvas.canvas;
            var ctx = imageCanvas.ctx;

            canvas.width = 1024;
            canvas.height = 1024;

            var imgAspectRatioAdjustedWidth, imgAspectRatioAdjustedHeight;
            var pushDownValueOnDy = 0;

            var grWidth = canvas.width / 1.618;
            if(img.width > img.height) {
                grWidth = canvas.width - grWidth;
            }
            var subtractFromDx = (canvas.width - grWidth) / 2;

            var grHeight = canvas.height / 1.618;
            if(img.height > img.height) {
                grHeight = canvas.height - grHeight;
            }
            var subtractFromDy = (canvas.height - grHeight) / 2;

            var dx = (canvas.width / 2);
            dx -= subtractFromDx;

            var dy = (canvas.height / 2);
            dy -= (subtractFromDy + pushDownValueOnDy);

            imgAspectRatioAdjustedWidth = (canvas.width - grWidth) + 50;
            imgAspectRatioAdjustedHeight = (canvas.height - grHeight) + 50;

            ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
            ctx.fillStyle = 'blue;'
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);  
            ctx.globalAlpha = 1.0;
            ctx.drawImage(img, dx, dy, imgAspectRatioAdjustedWidth, imgAspectRatioAdjustedHeight);
        });
```

After this the canvas data is added to an array to be painted onto the object - it is at this point that the CanvasTexture gets the mapped canvas:

```
            var canvasTexture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(mainCanvas.canvas);
            canvasTexture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
            canvasTexture.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;

            // Flip the canvas
            if(this.currentSide === 'front' || this.currentSide === 'back'){
                canvasTexture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
              canvasTexture.repeat.x = -1;
            }
            canvasTexture.needsUpdate = true;

            // { ...overdraw: true... } seems to allow the other sides to be transparent so we can see inside
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: canvasTexture, side: THREE.FrontSide, transparent: false});

            for(var i = 0; i < this.layers[this.currentSide].length; i++) {
                mainCanvas.ctx.drawImage( this.layers[this.currentSide][i].canvas, 0, 0, this.canvasWidth, this.canvasHeight);
            }
```

Comment: What is the resolution of the original starbucks image?

Comment: It's 198 × 200 (width x height) How does resolution play a role here?

Comment: Say you have some image, and it has some kind of an edge running at an angle. If you display a 198 x 200 image, in a 198 x 200 area on the screen, you'll get a 1:1 mapping. The "steps" on that slanted edge, are all jumping by one. If you then render the same image in a 396x400 area, you are renderng the image at 2:1, so the "steps" of the slanted edge now jump by two pixels. Any image viewing software should be able to replicate this. The feature should be called "zoom" in most of them.

Comment: The squares / blocks you are seeing are the pixels of the image that have been scaled up to fit your canvas. Use a larger image, preferably one with a resolution the same as your canvas

Comment: Is the size of the canvas the same as it's resolution? As you have seen above I can change the size of the canvas as I want so perhaps if I check the size of the image against the dimensions of the canvas I'd have a better result?

Comment: You are working with the information (pixels) from the image, so the only way to get a better result is to have more information (more pixels) in the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @2pha for the help as his suggestions lead me to the correct answer and, it turns out, that the pixelated effect was caused by different dimensions of the canvases.

For example the main canvas itself was 1024x1024 whereas the text & image canvases were only 512x512 pixels meaning that it would have to be stretched to cover the size of the main canvas.